# Excel VBA Clear content - Monthly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to clear range on last working day each month.

I have following formula to find EOM: `=WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A2,0)+1,-1)`

```
'Clear content Monthly
bookingWS.Range("A2") = Date
If Range("A2").Value = Range("B2") Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D100").ClearContents
End If
```

The problem I have is that I need the stored data to be cleared at the end of each day because throughout the day I'm still collecting the data.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What triggers the code?

Comment: Why not Clear on the first Open of the month (so basically onOpen the code checks if the month of the last edit and the current month are different, if so it resets) - Functionality wise that's pretty much the same what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question isn't so clear at the moment. Are you trying to trigger the code only on the last working day of the month? If so, please edit to say so. You can use Worksheet_Change event to trigger the code and add a condition to check if today is the last working day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

example:

modify accordingly

it will check every hour then will clear range at 5pm

```
Sub clearRange()

Dim bookingWS As Worksheet
bookingWS = ActiveSheet

    If Hour(Now()) = 17 Then 'check if 5pm
        'Clear content Monthly
        bookingWS.Range("A2") = Date
        If Range("A2").Value = Range("B2") Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D100").ClearContents
        End If
    End If

    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "clearRange" 'run every hour
    
End Sub
```

then on workbook open

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    clearRange
End Sub
```

if you want to stop the loop use

```
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now() + TimeValue("01:00:00"), _ 
 Procedure:="clearRange", Schedule:=False
```

Comment: what if excel isn't open at 5 pm; what if I close excel at 3pm and go home. It will not work. This will not clear the sheet reliably, since it is dependent on Excel being open and the code being run at the right times.

Comment: another issue is the infinite Application.OnTime loop that is triggered onOpen. You can end up with dozens of simultaneously running loops since onOpen starts a loop but closing the workbook doesn't terminate the loop. So yeah not a good idea

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII hence the modify accordingly, im very much open to a better code than mine